# How can I wrap a std::function and have easy access to its return and argument types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to do something that simplifies to the following:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct func_wrapper
{
public:
    using Func = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;

    Ret operator()(Args && ...args)
    {
        return _impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void another_function(int another_arg, Args && ...args) { }
    /// and so on

private:
   Func _impl;
};

func_wrapper<void(int, float)> f;
```

Basically, I want to make a type that wraps a `std::function` and adds some other functionality for my application. Inside my type, I would like to be able to use the return type `Ret` and argument parameter pack `Args` freely in the class interface. However, [when I try to compile the above with gcc 8.3, I get an error](https://godbolt.org/z/6j_D-B):

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct func_wrapper<void(int, float)>':
<source>:20:32:   required from here
<source>:9:45: error: function returning a function
     using Func = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
                                             ^
<source>:11:9: error: function returning a function
     Ret operator()(Args && ...args)
```

I'm not sure what to make of that error. Is there a straightforward way to do what I want?

Comment: Notice that your `operator()` actually uses rvalue references (unless for case as `func_wrapper<void(int&, const float&)>`) (there are fixed by class). You probably need `Ret operator()(Args...args)` or make `operator()` template with its own parameters (which can then use forwarding reference)

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks, good point. My intent was to use universal references, but I forgot that won't kick in unless `operator()` is a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have to use partial specialization

```
template <typename>
struct func_wrapper;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct func_wrapper<Ret(Args...)>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

If you write

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct func_wrapper
 {
   // ...
 };
```

declaring `f` as

```
func_wrapper<void(int, float)> f;
```

you have that `Ret` is deduced as `void(int, float)` and the `Args...` variadic list is deduced as an empty list.

So, when you define

```
using Func = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
```

the `Func` declaration become

```
// ............................V..........VVV  function-function type ?
using Func = std::function<void(int, float)()>;
```

that gives the "error: function returning a function" error.

You have to declare `func_wrapper` as receiving a single typename

```
template <typename>
struct func_wrapper;
```

so you can pass the type of the function (`void(int, float)` in your example) as template parameter, and then a template specialization

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct func_wrapper<Ret(Args...)>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

can resolve return type and arguments types from the function type.

Comment: That works! Can you elaborate on why that's required?

Comment: @JasonR - answer improved.

Answer (score 5):

@max66's answer does a great job showing how to avoid the issue you're running into. For more info about what specifically isn't working here, take a look at how you've parameterized your template and how you've used it:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args> struct func_wrapper {
     ...
};
```

This means that your template expects that you'll instantiate it by writing something like

```
func_wrapper<int, float> // Function taking a float and returning an int
func_wrapper<void, int, float> // Function taking a float and an int and returning void
func_wrapper<int> // Function taking no arguments and returning void
```

Notice, in particular, that `func_wrapper<T>` means that `Ret` will be `T` and the function will take no arguments.

As a result, when you write

```
func_wrapper<void(int, float)>
```

you're saying "a function representing something that takes no arguments and returns a function that takes in an `int` and a `float` and returns `void`," which isn't what you wanted. That's why you're getting the error about returning a function being illegal.